# Ссылки без адреса не работает корректно

Tags: javascript, html5

Доброго времени всем. В моем проекте ссылки без адреса
`<a href="#"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>`
не работают корректно. Они перенаправляет на домашний страницу. Я не смог определит причину.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: А что у вас в <base> находится? Текущая страница или домашняя? [линк](http://htmlbook.ru/html/base)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно на клик по ссылке повешен какой-то js, делающий редерект? Попробуйте отключить js в браузере, перезагрущить страницу и кликнуть по ссылке, если редеракта не произойдет - дело в js. :)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте что написано в  в шапке. И можно написать что-то аля такого, если подключен JQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  if($(this).attr('href') === "#") {
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

ну это скорее костыль, чем реальное решение.